# Searchview erro layout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda vez que clico para pesquisar a pesquisa empurra as tabs para baixo gostaria que as tabs ficassem fixas e o searchview se expandisse sem empurrar as Tabs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/main_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context="rg.listatelefonica.activity.MainActivity">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/altura_seachview_top"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<com.lapism.searchview.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/altura_tabs_top"
    />
```

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```